# GitHub finds commits that can't be found on git cli

Tags: git, github

I was asked to add a tag to a commit the was about two months old and was no longer being referenced. I could not find reference to the hash that was given to me via the cli. I can't find a way to get my local workspace to pull in unreferenced commits to find the "lost" commit.

I went to our GitHub instance and did a search on the hash. GH found reference to it in some old pull requests. I went through the pull request to look at the state of the repo at that time and then created a branch from there. Then I went to the cli, checked out that new branch and tagged it and pushed it up.

I think I should be able to do all of this through the cli. I'd prefer not having to lean on GH when I don't have to. Thanks for some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub typically does not garbage collect objects found in repositories (although this behavior is not guaranteed).  Thus, if you have an object that isn't referenced anywhere, it may still exist on GitHub but won't be cloned to your system, since Git will only fetch those objects that are referenced.

This is the case because Git has no way of knowing to fetch an object it doesn't have a reference for, so it won't fetch them unless you specifically request them.

If the object you're looking for is part of a pull request, you can try fetching the pull request ref.  They are called `refs/pull/NUMBER/head`, where `NUMBER` is the pull request number.  So to fetch pull request 42 into the `temp` branch, you can run this:

```
git fetch origin refs/pull/42/head:temp
```

However, if the commit you want is really an older version of a pull request, then it likely is completely unreferenced.  If so, you can use protocol version 2 with a recent version of Git to fetch that commit.  Note that only protocol version 2 allows you to fetch arbitrary commits; that's otherwise restricted.  So if you wanted to fetch `af6b65d45ef179ed52087e80cb089f6b2349f4ec` into `temp`, you could write:

```
git -c protocol.version=2 fetch origin af6b65d45ef179ed52087e80cb089f6b2349f4ec:temp
```

Not all servers support protocol version 2, but GitHub does.

Once you have the commit, you can tag and push as normal.

Comment: Interesting: v2 *always* allows access by raw hash ID? (It seems like it would have to do that for promisor packs to work right.)

Comment: The built-in implementation of v2 always allows access by raw hash.  That need not be required for other implementations, but it is definitely required for partial clones.

Comment: Thanks! This works for me so I'm accepting this as the solution.